# ArcGIS 10.2 objectid returning non sequential values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, objectid

I am making a SQL insert in a geotable. I'm getting the objectid via:

```
sde.gdb_util.next_rowid('my_user', 'my_table')
```

However, I've noticed that numbers given are not always in sequence. For instance, if I run the script 6 times, I get:

```
run|oid
---|------
  1| 1601
  2| 1602
  3| 1603
  4| 1917
  5| 1918
  6| 1604
```

Is this normal?

I know that for ids the only important thing is uniqueness, and sequentiality is optional, but I'm intrigued.

Comment: Yes, it's normal on database platforms where unused previously allocated values can be recycled (e.g. Oracle pipes), otherwise you may get holes.

Comment: Cross posted at https://community.esri.com/thread/203481-arcgis-102-objectid-returning-non-sequential-values