# ArcGIS SDE next rowid value doesn't increase at a constant rate

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.5, postgresql-9.5

Using ArcGIS 10.5.1 and Postgresql 9.5 database, I created a point feature class named Locations. After I inserted 8 points in my Locations table, the objectid value of last row is 8.

An hour later, when I inserted a new point to the Locations table the object id value created as 408. But it should be 9.

Several hours later when I inserted a new Location, the objectid created 1220.

*Why don't objectid values increase at a constant rate?*

Comment: Who says it should be 9?

Comment: The answer to this is embedded in the last question you asked on this topic -- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266461/arcgis-sde-i5-i6-i7-tables

Comment: See also:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258210/arcgis-10-2-objectid-returning-non-sequential-values

Comment: @KirkKuykendall,  nobody said it should ne 9. But I think if a sequential object assigned to a table by database, it should be increase after insert. But it changes not inserted yet.